# Shuffle characters in a string in Swift

Tags: swift, string, shuffle

Can the new Swift 5 shuffle() method be used (directly, or in a more complicated incantation) to randomly shuffle the characters in a Swift string variable?  (of length greater than 1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply try this nifty code

```
extension String {
    func shuffleString(minLength : Int) -> String{
        return self.count > minLength ? String(self.shuffled()) : self
    }
}


var string = "Whatever is your string"
print(string.shuffleString(minLength: 1))
```

[image]

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Now I have modified my answer according to the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can maybe try something like this.

```
var str = "Hello" 
var shuffledString = String(str.shuffled())
```

Comment: shuffledString is `[String.Element]`, not a string.

Comment: I think if you `init` with a `String` it's a `String`

Answer (score 0):

try this function

```
func shuffleString(word: String) -> String {
var chars = Array(word.characters)
var result = ""

while chars.count > 0 {
    let index = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(chars.count - 1)))
    chars[index].writeTo(&result)
    chars.removeAtIndex(index)
}

return result
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```swift
var str = "Shuffle me please"
var shuffledStr: [Character]

if !str.isEmpty {
   shuffledStr = str.shuffled()
   print(String(shuffledStr))
}
```